# Phase difference between source voltage and inductor voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, electric-circuits, inductance

[image]What will be the phase difference between the source voltage and the inductor voltage? Will the two voltages be in phase or will be out of phase. How much out of phase they will be?

Note that there is resistance in the circuit

Answer (score 2):

Both the voltages have to be out of phase by $180^o$. This comes from Kirchoff's law. V + $V_L$ = 0.

Therefore V=$-V_L$
This holds good even if there is no resistance for the inductor.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that there is resistance in the circuit, but did not draw it. I will assume that you intend the  resistance to be in series with the inductance.

In that case we can treat the circuit as a simple voltage divider using complex impedance. The impedance for the resistor is $Z_R=R$ and the impedance for the inductance is $Z_L=j\omega L$. Putting that into the voltage divider equation we get: $$V_L=\frac{j\omega L}{R+j\omega L}V$$

So the phase difference will depend on the exact values of $R$, $L$, and $\omega$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the resistance is.

If it’s in the wires between the source and the inductor then the answer given by @Dale applies. If it’s the resistance within the coil then the answer given by @Vilvanesh applies. If it is distributed between the wires and the coil you would need to specify the amounts to determine the voltage across the coil and its phase.

Hope this helps